# Why is class constraint on generic type not enforced?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I've got following interface definition

```
public interface IEncryptor
{
    T Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedData) where T : class;
}
```

with this implementation (which shouldn't be relevant)

```
internal class ThingyEncryptor : IEncryptor
{
    public T Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedData) where T : class
    {
        var encryptedSymmetricKey = encryptedData.Take(SymmetricKeyLength).ToArray();
        var iv = encryptedData.Skip(SymmetricKeyLength).Take(IvLength).ToArray();
        var symmetricEncryptedData = encryptedData.Skip(SymmetricKeyLength + IvLength).ToArray();

        using (var rsa = _certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
            var symmetricKey = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedSymmetricKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
            var clearData = Decrypt(symmetricEncryptedData, symmetricKey, iv);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clearData));
        }
    }
}
```

Reading [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), it is stated:

> If client code uses a type that doesn't satisfy a constraint, the
> compiler issues an error

I can't see any compiler warning or error when calling the `Decrypt` method like this (where `IMyModel` is really an interface and NOT a class):

```
_encryptor.Decrypt<IMyModel>(x.Patient)
```

Why?

This code is part of a nestandard20 project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the `class` [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), it enforces provided type argument to be a reference type:

> The type argument must be a reference type. This constraint applies also to any class, **interface**, delegate, or array type.

Comment: Yea, poor naming on C# side